# Bootstrap 3 columns with image & text responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-images

The code below displays 3 columns, each with an image and text that resize down on a smaller screen and finally to 1 column on a smartphone.  There are 2 problems : 1/ on the smallest screen, the image is too big and 2/ the text is under the image (like on the big screen) but I want it on the side of the image (half size of the smallest screen).

I looked at many example, but I can not find something simple...

How can I achieve this easily with Bootstrap?

```
<div class="container BSC_Angel">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <div class="col-sm-4 text-center" style="">
        <div>image 1</div>
        <div>text 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 text-center" style="">
        <div>image 2</div>
        <div>text 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 text-center" style="">
        <div>image 3</div>
        <div>text 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **CSS Flexbox**.

Have a look at this **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dOMGxy)**.

Or have a look at the snippet below (*`use full screen to view this properly`*):

```css
.content-holder {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

/* On Mobiles (screen width <= 767px) */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .content-holder {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  
  .text-div {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container BSC_Angel">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">

      <div class="col-sm-4 text-center" style="">
        <div class="content-holder">
          <div class="img-div"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""></div>
          <div class="text-div">Text 1</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4 text-center" style="">
        <div class="content-holder">
          <div class="img-div"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""></div>
          <div class="text-div">Text 2</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4 text-center" style="">
        <div class="content-holder">
          <div class="img-div"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""></div>
          <div class="text-div">Text 3</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you but in this case the text is always on the right side of the image even on big screen.  What I want to achieve is this but only on smallest screen.

Comment: @PaulGodard You need to use media queries to achieve this. I've updated my answer and Codepen as well, please have a look at them & let me know if this works?

Comment: Perfect! I have just added   .img-div { max-width:50%; } for mobile... Thank you @SauravRastogi